# Calculating time difference using textbox as value input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timespan

I have a text box and the user enters 16.30 how would I take that value and compute it as 16hrs and 30mins in order to get the correct time difference

Comment: this a web app, or forms app, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is for fully qualified dates and times. It sounds like what you want is [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx), which can handle time differences in hours, minutes, seconds, etc.